# How to get Android Studio to index cpp files when AOSP is loaded as a project?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

I have loaded AOSP into Android studio for debugging some Java code. However, I also want Android studio to index the cpp files so that it can find function declarations when I ctrl+click on them. However when I do so currently, it shows me an error saying "Cannot find declaration to go to" for any and all functions, elements, pretty much anything thats inside the cpp files.

Loaded AOSP into Android studio using idegen command and loading the .ipr file. I am using the ctrl+click on the functions inside the file ManifestFixer.cpp inside the aapt2 folder (/frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/link) and I want AS to show me the function declaration for the following code:

```
static xml::XmlNodeAction::ActionFuncWithDiag RequiredAndroidAttribute(const std::string& attr) { 
 ...some code...
}
```

When I click on (say) RequiredAndroidAttribute, it should redirect me to its declaration, which it does not. How do I enable cpp support in AS for AOSP?